# Visualstudio appcenter cannot find keystore file Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /Users/runner/runners/2.166.2/work/1/s/RMobile/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Xamarin/Mono for Android/Keystore/***/***.keystore (No such file or directory

I get this error in appcenter

[image]

Comment: Do you have any .jks file or .keystore file?

Comment: yes i have a keystorefile. everything seemed to work before.the last updated i did on the app was last year and now did a few updates and planned to push today to  visualstudio appcenter throws this error during build.

It works in debug mode, in release mode in my emulator too. But fails to build in visual studio appcenter

Comment: There is a .keyinfo file in the same directory. Can you delete it and try again? Delete the .keyinfo file.

Comment: thats on my local drive, the issue im having is within visualstudio appcenter remote build. I'll try that anyway. Just a minute. i updated it with a photo. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously something changed in appcenter or xamarin.
The solution was to uncheck the checkbox in the build configuration that says "**sign the .APK file using the following keystore details"**

after i pushed to appcenter the build worked. Thanks @cbalakus

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people ;)